# Scatter plot and boxplot overlay

Tags: r, ggplot2

Based on the previous post [ggplot boxplots with scatterplot overlay (same variables)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14707952/ggplot-boxplots-with-scatterplot-overlay-same-variables),

I would like to have **one boxplot for each day of week** instead of two boxplots **while have scatter points on it with different colour.**

The code will be like:

```
#Box-plot for day of week effect
plot1<-ggplot(data=dodgers, aes(x=ordered_day_of_week, y=Attend)) + geom_boxplot()

#Scatter with specific colors for day of week
plot2<-ggplot(dodgers, aes(x=ordered_month, y=Attend, colour=Bobblehead, size=1.5)) + geom_point()

#Box-ploy with Scatter plot overlay
plot3<-ggplot(data=dodgers, aes(x=ordered_day_of_week, y=Attend, colour=Bobblehead)) + geom_boxplot() + geom_point()
```

And the result would be: 
1, scatter plot

[image]

2, boxplot plot
[image]

3, combined plot
[image]

Comment: If you supply the individual aesthetics to the `geom_point` and `geom_boxplot` separately, you should be able to resolve this issue.

Comment: Ohh thanks! thats what i want! Many thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put `color=` inside the `aes()` of `geom_point()` and remove it from `ggplot()` `aes()`. If you put `color=` inside the `ggplot()` then it affects all geoms. Also you could consider to use position dodge to separate points.

Example with `mtcars` data as OP didn't provide data.

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(factor(cyl),mpg))+geom_boxplot()+
  geom_point(aes(color=factor(am)),position=position_dodge(width=0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, This is a great solution! But, I would like to know one more thing. How to move the dots to the side of boxplots instead of overlapping them together?

Comment: also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468380/overlay-geom-points-on-geom-boxplotfill-group