# Array (different dates, values), boxplots: x - dates, y - values

Tags: r, boxplot

I'm new using R. I have such data:

```
Date;Value

2019-01-31;125

2019-01-31;127

2019-01-31;120

2019-01-31;116

2019-01-31;119

...

2019-02-01;222

2019-02-01;233

2019-02-01;225

2019-02-01;222

2019-02-01;222

...


2019-02-02;111

2019-02-02;234

2019-02-02;876

2019-02-02;234

2019-02-02;983

...
```

Now I have data from two months, but there will be more. One day = 288 records.

I would like to create boxplots something like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdrLI.jpg where `V12 = date1`, `v11 = date2`, ...

Pictures source: [Plot boxplot and overlayed data points for matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33212843/plot-boxplot-and-overlayed-data-points-for-matrix)

I have read above topic, but I have a different array. Could you help me?

Comment: what did you try to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a dataframe, you can use the library **ggplot2** and the function `geom_boxplot()` to create one boxplot per each date.

```
df <- data.frame(
  Date  = c(rep('2019-01-31', 50), rep('2019-02-01', 50)),
  Value = round(rnorm(100, 150, 50))
)

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Value)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did not know the geom_boxplot function. R did not find %>%, but based on your answer I found a solution at http://r-statistics.co/Top50-Ggplot2-Visualizations-MasterList-R-Code.html.

Eventually, the following code worked:
df <- data.frame (
  Date = c (rep ('2019-01-31', 50), rep ('2019-02-01', 50)),
  Value = round (rnorm (100, 150, 50))
)

library (ggplot2)

g <- ggplot (df, aes (x = Date, y = Value))
g + geom_boxplot ()

Comment: you need to load `library(dplyr)` for using the pipe `%>%`

Comment: Thx, I will do that.