# how do i add scatter points to a box plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am trying to add external scatter points(points 10, 20 and 30)  to a box plot. I have the code

```
ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(data = mtcars, 
               aes(x = factor(cyl), y= mpg)) +
  geom_point(data = data.frame(x = factor(cyl), y = c(10,20,30)),
             aes(x=x, y=y),
             color = 'red')
```

I keep getting the error :

> Error in factor(cyl) : object 'cyl' not found

Comment: Try with `data = data.frame(x = factor(c(4, 6, 8)), y = c(10,20,30))`. `cyl` is no variable in your working space.

Comment: check the link mentioned if it comes in handy. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22074164/scatter-plot-and-boxplot-overlay